# reading a file and saving in an array

Tags: c, arrays, file, scanf

I want a simple C program, which will read a file and saves the content of each line to an array element. The file contains all the integer value. Only one integer value is present per line. In this way each of the integer value is to stored in an array.

Comment: Okay, what have you done so far, and what problems have you encountered in doing so?

Comment: try [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) and [`strtol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example which does what you ask, with error checking, and dynamically resizing your array as more data is read in.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char buf[512];
    FILE * f;
    int * array = 0;
    size_t array_len = 0, count = 0;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please provide a filename to read\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(&buf[0], 512, f) != 0) {
        if (count == array_len) {
            array_len *= 2;
            if (array_len == 0) {
                array_len = 32;
            }
            array = realloc(array, array_len * sizeof(int));
            if (array == NULL) {
                perror("realloc");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        array[count++] = strtol(buf, 0, 10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many web resources to help you in this regard. a fast google search  [pointed me to this example](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/92034)

which, beside the non dynamic nature of the example, does what you want with scanf.